# Are there a css property that would change nothing and where we can store information?

Tags: css

Are there a css property that would change nothing?

I need this for testing purposes very often when writing `scss` just to see that I created a css selector correctly. For instance, I would be glad to have something like this `foo: "helloworld1";` and later on I would be able to change the value of the `foo` and check the value in the developer tools to see that my selectors have indeed reached a correct element.

I thought about using the `width: auto;`, but sometimes the width is specified (e.g. `width: 100px;`).

Comment: Feels like an XY problem to me, because that's not the point of using CSS.

Comment: Any invalid property is ignored by browsers, so you can use `something: something;`.

Comment: @Terry, oh. Indeed the `zoom` is rarely modified. Thank you.

Comment: @D.Pardal, oh. That is a useful piece of info. Seems like I won`t be able to achieve what I need. :(

Comment: @Terry, so. When you write `scss` which has complicated expressions for selecting elements, how do you verify that you have written the scss expression correctly?

Comment: @Terry, also I would be curious to hear what is the point of using CSS. Not what CSS is used for. :)

Comment: How about seeing in the UI that your styles are correct? Or how about setting a specific unusual style like `background-color: red;` to see if your selectors are correct or not? Wouldn't these solve your problem?

Comment: use CSS variables https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi, no that would not solve my problem. The existence of the `background-color: red;` does not mean that my selector expression is correct since the `background-color: red;` might have been there before I have written my selector expression. I.e. it might be that I was not the one who has added the style.

Comment: @TemaniAfif, that is what I was looking for. Thank you. I think you could post it as an answer. (y)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define your own properties using [custom properties (aka CSS variables)](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables-1/)

> Custom properties are solely for use by authors and users; CSS will never give them a meaning beyond what is presented here.

Also

> Custom properties are ordinary properties, so they can be declared on any element, are resolved with the normal inheritance and cascade rules, can be made conditional with @media and other conditional rules, can be used in HTML’s style attribute, can be read or set using the CSSOM, etc.