# Possible to store a key-value pair in css?

Tags: html, css

I have tens of millions of `td` cells and I want to store some information in them. I could do it with something like the following approach:

```
<td type="number" format="financial">4.00</td>
```

But this balloons the size of the data, which I need to keep compact due to the volume of the cells. I am trying to copy the table data into my clipboard buffer (for example, to paste into Excel), and so I cannot exceed the allowable string-size in the browser, which is anywhere from ~250MB-1GB or so.

Ideally, I would like to store the type data as a css class. Something like this:

```
.x19 {
    "type": "number",
    "format": "financial"
}
...
<td class="x19">4.00</td>
```

In this way, I can group the formats at the top, and not have to replicate that block of text tens of millions of times. Is there a way to do this somehow with css -- that is, to be able to 'lookup' the `x19` class and be able to somehow retrieve one or more k/v pairs? (Note that I only have access to css and html, javascript is not allowed here.)

Perhaps something like:

```
.x19:after{
    content: "{type:'number', format:'financial'}";
    display: hidden;
}
```

Comment: use css variables: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62716281/8620333

Comment: @TemaniAfif thanks, would you want to show an example for the above case. Would it just be: `.x19 { --type: "number"; --format: "financial"}`, or how do I store things like strings, etc. ?

Comment: You are free to use the format you want, simply make sure to have a valid syntax at the end

Comment: ^ in your example you will need `;` and not `,`

Comment: @TemaniAfif thanks for pointing that out. Is it common to quote the strings or how are those usually done?

Comment: since you will not use them anywhere it doesn't matter to have quote or not but using quote is more safe in case you have space, special character, etc